# What is the official name for this icon/button?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, interface

What is the official name for this button/icon:

[image]

It's found in many places throughout Blender:

[image] [image]

I can't find it anywhere in the manual.

If you know, can you please cite the source for your information (i.e. a page from the Blender Manual) because I'd like to read about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Andrew Price called it "Dot Symbol" button:

http://youtu.be/xYiiD-p2q80?t=8m58s

I would call the particular ones you show "Node Material Properties Dropdown Buttons" to be honest. I'm not sure why a differnet icon is used here, using a symbol not "universaly understood" like Andrew said.

Comment: I understood the icon to mean "click this to connect a new node here" (specifically a node), as the dot reminds me of node sockets.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it documented anywhere in the manual but it looks like it is using icon ID of `LAYER_USED`. That is the same icon shown in the 3dview header to show that something is on that layer.

A popup menu normally has two arrows but the cycles materials where this is shown are used for node links and line [1380 of interface_widgets.c](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/interface/interface_widgets.c) supports that theory. What the if statement surrounding that line says is if it is drawing a menu and it is flagged as a node link it draws the layer used icon which elsewhere would also prevent the two little arrows being drawn, that matches with the cycles material display.

Other places `LAYER_USED` can be found is in the addons - Layer Manager, Node Wrangler and PowerLib.

It would appear that the use you have shown is unique to the cycles material display as part of a popup menu and is hard coded that way. From an addon usage we don't get direct access to show it as part of a popup menu, I haven't tried but you may be able to flag the menu as a node link to make it work.